# Wampserver .dll's: sysvmsg sysvsem

Tags: wampserver

I've been bend over backwards, Google'd for an hour, does anyone know WHICH .dll library (I'm running Windows XP/64, wampserver PHP/5.4.3) holds sysvsem and sysvmem functions and where I can actually find it?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows? None of them. The underlying functions that those extensions expose don't exist on Windows.

Comment: The "sysv" in the extension names stands for "System V", a reference to the version of UNIX that added these IPC primitives. Windows is not UNIX, and hence never adopted the SysV IPC model, so these functions don't exist.